# Azure Store the image for Mobile

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

May I ask about how to store the image to Microsoft Azure?
Should I use blob storage or SQL?
Which method recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, not sure are you trying to store from website or mobile. I'll break down the questions piece by piece.

1) How to store images to Azure?
a) Answer: It depends what workload that you're using. If you're using Azure Web App, you can straight store it into filesystem. Assuming if you're using ASP.NET, this is how you do it

```
if (FileUploader.HasFile)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUploader.PostedFile.FileName);

    FileUploader.PostedFile.SaveAs("~/Images/") + fileName);        
}
```

Then you can save the path to SQL database.

b) If you plan to use blob storage for creating multi-tier application and off-loading IO process, then this is how you do it

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"path\myfile"))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

2) Should you use blob or sql?
You would want to use blob instead to store the images to off-load the IO. You would also face the issue of increasing database size if you save them into sql. However, being dependent on blob also increase your dependency on Azure, as you can't migrate them easily. You should just use SQL or NoSQL to store the link to your images file

Hope this helps